# Issues with FileReader and Java GUI/jForm

Tags: java, swing, io, filereader, jform

I am trying to make a smaller version of Pwned Passwords (https://haveibeenpwned.com/Passwords) for my Ap comp sci project. Everything is goo besides 2 things:

---

[(Issue 1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exyFs.png) (image of my code to show better)
I have this below my jForm source code which declares each button/etc and what they do. I get this error though: "Illegal static declaration in inner class PassCheck.check. I do not now how to resolve this issue.

---

The second issue is using FileReader and Buffered Reader. I want the program to read the text inputted from the jForm and compare it to a file which has a list of commonly used passwords. How can I do this? Here is my code so far of just practicing with FR and BR:

```
    import java.io.*;

public class MainFileReader {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    
      String refpass, input;
      input = "1234";
      
      FileReader fr = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\tcoley\\Downloads\\207pass.txt");
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

    while((input = br.readLine()) != null){
        refpass = br.readLine();
```

And I stopped here. I apologize as Java is not my strong suit but any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Re 'Issue 1': Each thread on Stack Overflow should contain exactly one problem/question, ideally with a [mre] specific to the problem. Since two people have already addressed the 2nd issue, it would be best to start a different thread in relation to the first. [Edit] to remove the first part from this question.

Comment: For your **issue #1** - [Read this Tutorial from Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) about nested classes. If you want to use the inner class as is, then remove the `static` modifier from the main() method declaration in that class, for example: `public void main(String[] args) {` OR make the inner class `static`, for example: `public static class Check {`.

Answer (score 1):

For your **issue #2** - `input` is the string variable that is to be used hold the password you want to find in the file yet you eliminate its contents when you apply it to reading a line: `(input = br.readLine())`. It will now hold the currently read file line (this is no good). You need to use the `refPass` variable instead, for example: `(refPass = br.readLine())`.

You only need to use `br.readLine()` once in your loop. What your code is effectively doing right now (if it runs) is reading two (2) file lines on each iteration of the `while` loop. It could potentially fall into an Exception since there is no protection for null in the second read. Again no good.

Once you've read a file line, ensure it actually contains something. A lot of times a file will have a blank line in it that can throw a monkey wrench into things if it's not handled. To check for this you can do something like what is shown below **after** a line is read into `refPass`:

```
while((refPass = br.readLine()) != null) {
    // remove leading & trailing whitespaces (if any).
    refPass = refPass.trim();
    // Skip past blank lines in file (if any).
    if (refPass.isEmpty()) {
        continue;
    }
    // .... rest of code ...
}
```

Now to complete your loop block code, you just need to compare the password read in with the password contained within the `input` variable (ex: `"1234"`). To do this, you could have something like this:

```
if (refPass.equals(input) {
    System.out.println("Password Found!")
    break; // Break out of the 'while' loop and close file.
}
```

**On a side:** Don't use `==` to compare Strings for ***content*** equality, that may not always work as you expect. Use the [String#equals()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-and-equals-method-in-java/) method instead. Give the supplied link a read.

At the end of and outside your `while` loop, be sure to close the reader, for example: `br.close();` so as to release hold on the file and free up resources.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use BufferedReader. Buffering is only for inefficient reading and writing (ie doing multiple reads and writes)

Use `Path` and `Files` instead

```
Path p = "C:\\Users\\tcoley\\Downloads\\207pass.txt";
String file = new String(Files.loadAllBytes(p));
```

Answer (score 0):

What does the file look like? There are a lot of ways to format a file and for simplicities sake, this will just assume it's one word per line:

With the line

```
    refpass = br.readLine();
```

You are taking in the line from the file

```
    boolean isEqual = refpas.equals(input);
```

This allows you to assess the line individually.
Remember that '==' is not the way to use String comparisons in Java.

```
    ("cat" == "cat") != ("cat".equals("cat"))
```